# How can I mass convert MIDIs to MP3s?

Tags: conversion, mp3, midi, audio-conversion

I happen to have multiple MIDIs, and I have to convert them to MP3s for a certain task.
I simply can't trust online convertors.

I have looked into using ffmpeg, but I believe it does not have MIDI support.

It doesn't matter what soundfont is used, since the only voice used is the piano.

How can I mass convert MIDIs to MP3s?

I am on Windows, but I can boot Lubuntu if needed.

Comment: Can you clarify what the limitation is in trusting online convertors (control of quality, security, etc.)?  Without knowing that, how will people know if the unknown limitation applies to whatever else they would recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Foobar 2000](http://www.foobar2000.org) is a good general purpose media player that has batch conversion abilities and also has a [midi decoder](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_midi) which can be used.

I've used Foobar in the past to do batch conversion from `.mod` music files to mp3 with good effect, but I do not know how well midi would fare or if you need to also download sound banks.

Their is a section on the [Foobar 2000 FAQ page](http://www.foobar2000.org/FAQ) that gives a quick overview of converting files.